# BOX-API: Trying to get a shared folder without a token 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: box-api

I want to interrogate a shared folder without having to log the user in, from reading the documentation, this should be fine to do, but if run the example within my command line:

curl https://api.box.com/2.0/shared_items \
-H "Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=YOUR_API_KEY&shared_link=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.box.com%2Fs%2F8tqjqtoky18sbnoz264c"

Using my API key it works fine, however, within my app or just within a web browser, if I use:

https://api.box.com/2.0/shared_items -H "Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=YOUR_API_KEY&shared_link=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.box.com%2Fs%2F8tqjqtoky18sbnoz264c"

again with my API key, I get 401 Unauthorized error.

What am I doing wrong? Is it an encoding issue? as it looks like the end part of the string needs to be encoded, however the rest of it doesn't, I have tried to make sure that the C# code I am using does not encode the string, and I think it is not, but it still fails with 401.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the shared link from the example that you're using (the one ending with 8tqjqtoky18sbnoz264c) is no longer a valid URL. You should go into the Box web app and create a new shared link to test with, and that should work.

Comment: I have tried it with an active share and I still get the same issue, here is a test shared folder https://app.box.com/s/khhllndt6v4zzurue94z it still says 401 Unauthorized on anything I try except for curl